# Proper case title for City, State including apostrophe

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = str_replace('\, ', '\,', ucwords(str_replace('\,', '\, ', strtolower($CapDeliveryCityANDState))));
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = strrev(ucfirst(strrev($CapDeliveryCityANDState)));
```

that makes the first letter capital of every word and the rest lowercase and after the comma "," it makes the first two letters capital, but I want to add another thing and to make a letter capital if there is a "'" so, so far what I have works great for this example:

`cHiCago, il` would become `Chicago, IL`

but if it was `o'fallon, mo` it would be `O'fallon, MO` but I would like it to be `O'Fallon, MO` (capital after the apostrophe)

Thanks for the help...

SOLUTION IS:

```
    $CapDeliveryCityANDState = str_replace('\, ', '\,', ucwords(str_replace('\,', '\, ', strtolower($CapDeliveryCityANDState))));
    $CapDeliveryCityANDState = strrev(ucfirst(strrev($CapDeliveryCityANDState)));
    if(strpos($CapDeliveryCityANDState, "'")) {
            $pos = strpos($CapDeliveryCityANDState, "'") + 1;
    }
    $CapDeliveryCityANDState = substr_replace($CapDeliveryCityANDState, strtoupper($CapDeliveryCityANDState[$pos]), $pos, 1);
    $CapDeliveryCityANDState[$l=strlen($CapDeliveryCityANDState)-2] = strtoupper($CapDeliveryCityANDState[$l]);
```

Added more to this code for anyone if they ever need it:

```
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = $contact_CityandStateSTR;
if(strlen($CapDeliveryCityANDState) >= 5){ //If more then 5 letters then do the below
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = str_replace('\, ', '\,', ucwords(str_replace('\,', '\, ', strtolower($CapDeliveryCityANDState))));
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = strrev(ucfirst(strrev($CapDeliveryCityANDState)));
if(strpos($CapDeliveryCityANDState, "'")) {
        $pos = strpos($CapDeliveryCityANDState, "'") + 1;
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = substr_replace($CapDeliveryCityANDState, strtoupper($CapDeliveryCityANDState[$pos]), $pos, 1);
}

$mystringz = $CapDeliveryCityANDState;
$findmez   = ',';
$posz = strpos($mystringz, $findmez);
if ($posz !== false) {
// IF NOT FALSE THEN CAP. LAST 2 LETTERS (STATE)
$CapDeliveryCityANDState[$l=strlen($CapDeliveryCityANDState)-2] = strtoupper($CapDeliveryCityANDState[$l]);
} else {
// ELSE IF FALSE THEN LEAVE AS IS
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = $contact_CityandStateSTR;
}
}
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = str_replace(" ,", ",", $CapDeliveryCityANDState); //remove space after city
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = str_replace(",", ", ", $CapDeliveryCityANDState); //add space after comma
$CapDeliveryCityANDState = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $CapDeliveryCityANDState); //Check and remove double space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the apostrophe with strstr(). If it exists, explode the values into the two parts (before and after the apostrophe), capitalize them, then implode() them on the apostrophe again.

Comment: Thank you this helped me get to the solution. I have updated the question and added the code above for anyone if they ever need it.